# terminator does not open maximized in ubuntu 23.04

Tags: 23.04, terminator

I've updated my Ubuntu from 22 to 23.04 and the `terminator` app which I use instead of its own terminal does not open maximized. without any changes, in ubuntu 22 when I press `ctrl`+`alt`+`t`, it opens maximized.

Comment: Before suspecting a problem, maximize the application, then close it. Does it now start maximized? Still, it might be a mutter issue in 23.04, where quite some things changed and (slightly) broke.

Comment: @vanadium, No it does not start maximized.

Comment: It will be good to add anything that you checked to the question itself: it helps delineating the problem more. Comments are not necessarily read and are primarily aimed to improve questions and answers. Also important is whether you run Wayland or Xorg.